# Next JS frequently downloads resources in Dev mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm new in NextJs. I created a simple page like this:

```
import Head from 'next/head';

const About = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>About</title>
      </Head>
      <div>
        <h1>About</h1>
        <p>This is About page.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default About;
```

But I noticed Next.js frequently downloads resources when I checked the network tab in devtools:

[image]

Even after re-opening the tab, that sends new req and fetches data...

Is it normal? or I have to manage it by configs?

Comment: It's normal. Notice `hmr` in `webpack-hmr`, it stands for Hot Module Reload. It's webpacks way of making changes in your code show without having to refresh the page.

Comment: @AriSeyhun you know, I added an API fetch and it was getting new resources, I thought it will be a problem in dev time, because that loads many data in background and uses bandwidth